# how to use libcurl as server?

Tags: c, linux, curl

can i use curl's functions to receive clients https connections? i want to write server using libcurl, should i use naked sockets to accept connections? Oficial documentation provides following example:

```
/* read the response */ 
for(;;)
{
  char buf[1024];

  wait_on_socket(sockfd, 1, 60000L);
  res = curl_easy_recv(curl, buf, 1024, &iolen);

  if(CURLE_OK != res)
    break;

  printf("Received %u bytes.\n", iolen);
}
```

but they always writes clients, not servers...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [LIBCURL - about](http://www.libcurl.org/)

> libcurl is a free, open source client to get documents/files from servers, using any of the supported protocols.

It is a *client* library not an HTTPS server.